# Can repo recurse submodules?

Tags: git, repo

We are starting to use repo ( https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html ) to manage our multi-repository projects, however some of these repositories are using git submodules. When I do a `repo sync`, is there a way to basically pass `--recursive` to the clone it is doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is YES. Two options:

1. in your manifest, you can specify the attribute sync-s="true"

   1. for example `<default sync-s="true"/>` to apply to all projects
   2. or for a specific project, `<project sync-s="true"/>`
2. do it as needed when you sync, with `repo sync --fetch-submodules`

`repo help manifest` really only hints at this capability.
Do not define submodules as `<project>`s as it seems to be suggested, this will screw them up during the checkout phase.